# Ожидание нажатия кнопки в цикле

Tags: c#, xamarin

Подскажите пожалуйста! Пишу мини програму тестирования, прописал создание интерфейса метод вызывается из main.

```
 private async void load_questions()
        {
            var data = await SendRequest(Url, "");

            Grid grid = new Grid
            {
                RowDefinitions =
                    {
                        new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
                        new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
                        new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
                        new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
                        new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
                        new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
                    },
                ColumnDefinitions =
                    {
                        new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
                    }
            };

            // Label wopros = new Label { Text = data[0].text_question, FontSize = 20, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center };

            int buf_prav = Result_test.prav;
            int buf_neprav = Result_test.neprav;

            while ((Result_test.prav == buf_prav) || (Result_test.neprav == buf_neprav))
            {



                Label wopros = new Label { Text = data[Result_test.k].text_question, BackgroundColor = Color.Gray };
                Label otwet1_ = new Label { Text = data[Result_test.k].text_Answers1 };
                Button otwet1 = new Button { Text = "Ответ 1" }; otwet1.Clicked += otwet1_Clicked;
                Label otwet2_ = new Label { Text = data[Result_test.k].text_Answers2 };
                Button otwet2 = new Button { Text = "Ответ 2" };
                Label otwet3_ = new Label { Text = data[Result_test.k].text_Answers3 };
                Button otwet3 = new Button { Text = "Ответ 3" };
                Label otwet4_ = new Label { Text = data[Result_test.k].text_Answers4 };
                Button otwet4 = new Button { Text = "Ответ 4" };
                Label otwet5_ = new Label { Text = data[Result_test.k].text_Answers5 };
                Button otwet5 = new Button { Text = "Ответ 5" };
                grid.Children.Add(wopros, 0, 0);
                grid.Children.Add(otwet1_, 0, 1);
                grid.Children.Add(otwet1, 0, 2);
                grid.Children.Add(otwet2_, 0, 3);
                grid.Children.Add(otwet2, 0, 4);
                if (data[Result_test.k].text_Answers3 != "нет ответа                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ")
                {
                    grid.Children.Add(otwet3_, 0, 5);
                    grid.Children.Add(otwet3, 0, 6);
                }
                if (data[Result_test.k].text_Answers4 != "нет ответа                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ")
                {
                    grid.Children.Add(otwet4_, 0, 7);
                    grid.Children.Add(otwet4, 0, 8);
                }
                if (data[Result_test.k].text_Answers5 != "нет ответа                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ")
                {
                    grid.Children.Add(otwet5_, 0, 9);
                    grid.Children.Add(otwet5, 0, 10);
                }
                ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView();
                scrollView.Content = grid;
                this.Content = scrollView;
                Content = grid;
            }

            int i = 1;
        }
```

А теперь встал вопрос как мне сделать что бы цикл ждал нажатия кнопки?

Comment: Какую кнопку должен ждать цикл?

Comment: Сейчас в коде определены только 5 кнопок вариантов ответа, ниже будет 6 с текстом "ответить"